# Unable to add circle user avatar on login form

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in web development and I have made a Signup form for a webpage . What I feel like is trully missing from the form is a circular avatar icon on top of it like the picture below :

[image: Login form with avatar on top in the middle]

I have html and css code and I have loaded an avatar icon . However I do not know how to place it on the top middle of the form just like the image . I would appreciate your help  and guidance with this task .
My code :

```css
//the avatar appears inside the page not on top 
.avatar{


height:500px;
border-radius:50%; 
 
} 




.form-area{

position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:500px;
height:600px;
box-sizing:border-box; 
background:rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
padding:40px; 
 
 
}





h1{

margin:0;
padding:0 0 20px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
  
} 

.form-area p {

margin:0;
padding:0;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
  
} 

.form-area input,select{

margin-bottom:20px;
width:100%; 
 
 
} 

.form area input[type=text], .form-area input[type="password"]
{

border:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
background-color:transparent; 
outline:none;
height:40px;
color:#ffffff;
display:16px;
 
 
} 





.form-area select{
 
margin-top:20px;
padding:10px 0;
 
 
} 


.signupbtn{

border:none;
height:40px;
outline:none;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:15px;
background-color:#4CAF50;
cursor:pointer; 
border-radius:20px; 
 
 
} 


.cancelbtn{

border:none;
height:40px;
outline:none;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:15px;
background-color:tomato;
cursor:pointer; 
border-radius:20px; 
 
 
} 



button:hover{
 
opacity:0.7; 
 
 
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-area">

 <form action="Start_page.html" class = "sign-form animate" onsubmit="return validateform()" method = "post">
 //the avatar I want to display on the form 
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="IMAGES/login.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
 
   <div class="container">
     <h1>Sign Up</h1>
     <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
     <hr>
  
  
    <label for="name" ><b><span>Name<span></b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="onoma" id = "myname" required>
 
 
    <label for="surname" ><b><span>Surname<span></b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="epith" id = "mysurname" required>

    <label for="email" ><b><span>Email<span></b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id = "mailID" required>

    <label for="psw"><b><span>Password</span></b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id = "pass" required>

 
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn" onclick = "window.location.href='Start_page.html'">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
 
   </div>
   
 </form>

 </div>
```

Thank you in advance . If you have any questions or need more information about my page tell me and I will update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the image:

```
.imgcontainer img{
    height: 100px; /* set a default height*/
    margin-top: -75px; /* move image up fo 75px */
    border: 1px solid black; /* define a border */
    border-radius: 50%; /* make the image rounded, this works only with square images*/
}
```

and this to it's container:

```
.imgcontainer{
    display: flex; /* change display */
    justify-content:center;/* align to the center the image */
    /* NOTE : there is a lot of other way to align the image to the center, you can use the one that you prefer*/
}
```

If this method does not do what you want in the way you want, another way is to use `position: absolute`, center it on center top, and than traslate it `-50% top` and `-50% left`

Comment: Thank you very much